# Is the Windows logo available?

Tags: symbols, windows

I'm surprised I don't see this addressed quickly with a Google search, but I don't see it there or on this site.

Does anyone know of a Windows logo symbol in LaTeX?  I used [Dextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but couldn't find it there.  I would think this has been asked many times, alas.

I might as well let you know the reason, too.  I'm writing instructions for a procedure for Windows, and it includes help with a shortcut (Windows Key + Escape key) that I would like to illustrate to make it foolproof.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [menukeys](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) would be the obvious place to put the symbol (includes a generic keytop defined as `\winmenu`) but they mention not including it for copyright reasons

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Indeed, there doesn't seem to be a Windows symbol neither in the [comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) nor in Unicode. This symbol is in the [WingDings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) font, but it is not available everywhere. Hence it appears one must use an external logo.

The German Wikipedia has a nice outline, monochrome [Windows logo](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Windows_3_logo_simplified.svg). It can be converted to an `.eps` or `.pdf` and then included in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{keystroke}

% Lower the picture a little to match the text baseline
\newcommand{\WindowsLogo}{\raisebox{-0.1em}{%
  \includegraphics[height=0.8em]{Windows_3_logo_simplified}}}
\newcommand{\WinKey}{\keystroke{\WindowsLogo}}

\begin{document}

Press \WinKey+\keystroke{E} to open Windows Explorer.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Very nice answer! I didn't know about the `keystroke` package

Answer (score 19):

Using XeLaTeX, you can make use of the free TrueType font [Illustrate IT](http://www.dafont.com/illustrate-it.font), which offers a large collection of product symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\winlogoblack}{{\fontspec{illustrate-it.ttf}c}}
\newcommand{\winlogowhite}{{\fontspec{illustrate-it.ttf}d}}
\begin{document}
    Filled logo: \winlogoblack. Empty logo: \winlogowhite.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output result]

Answer (score 16):

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) provides a number of operating system logos (compile with XeLaTeX/LauLaTeX):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontawesome}

\newcommand{\faWindows}{\FA\symbol{"F17A}}
\newcommand{\faLinux}{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}
\newcommand{\faApple}{\FA\symbol{"F179}}

\begin{document}

\verb|Windows:| \faWindows \par
\verb|Linux  :| \faLinux \par
\verb|Apple  :| \faApple

\end{document}
```

To find the corresponding hex symbol identifiers, see the [Font Awesome cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

Comment: Looks like the updated Windows 11 logo is called `\faMicrosoft` or `\faIcon{Microsoft}`: 

https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this: <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Just include the logo as a picture using `\includegraphics`.