# How can I visualize key press combinations?

Tags: text-decorations, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

One of my favorite Wiki-Sites (ubuntuusers.de) allows the editors to add key combinations.

```
[[Template(Keys, Strg+T)]]
[[Template(Keys, Strg+Shift+Tab)]]
[[Template(Keys, Strg+lmt)]] (for left mouse)
```

Rendered example:

[image]

Can I make something similar in LaTeX? Is there a package that also has the "Windows Key"?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/how-to-typeset-special-apple-mac-keyboard-symbols

Comment: and another one : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13739/is-the-windows-logo-available :)

Comment: Thanks percusse! `menukeys` is defenitely interesting for menus and key cominations, but this <kbd>tab</kbd> looks a bit nicer. And `keystroke.sty` causes an error: "! LaTeX Error: Command \Return already defined."

Comment: @moose You ask very good questions, but they tend to get closed relatively frequently (7 out of 33), I assume mostly as duplicates. Make sure to search for existing questions thoroughly before posting. Often, I get the best search results when I use tags for searching rather than words.

Comment: @doncherry: I am always searching for answers in Google before I ask questions, because I need very long to ask a question (in fact, asking a question takes almost always more time than finding one). I also try tag search (not always, but often), but I don't know which keywords I could try. For this question I had problems finding only one keyword that seemed to fit. I guess my "duplicate question problem" could also be a language problem. As I am a foreign english speaker, its possible that I tend to formulate questions different than others.

Comment: @doncherry: Furthermore, somebody told me that making duplicates on StackExchange isn't bad, if the question is formulated in a different way. So if other users search with similar keywords, they will find my question and get to the good answers. Is this wrong?

Comment: @moose: Fair enough, we can't expect more than you trying, and sometimes it is really hard to find question, especially if English isn't your native language. You're right about duplicates helping people to find the right question, that's why we usually don't delete them. That just shouldn't keep you from searching thoroughly, but it seems like you did that. The tags for this question are kinda tricky, I agree.