# Windows logo from fontawesome does not work

Tags: fontawesome

I was looking at an answer here that suggests to use Font Awesome to get the Windows logo: [Is the Windows logo available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13739/is-the-windows-logo-available)

However it does not seem to work here, and when I copy/paste the code I don't get any logo. Could you explain how to use the Windows logo from fontawesome?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontawesome}

\newcommand{\faWindows}{\FA\symbol{"F17A}}
\newcommand{\faLinux}{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}
\newcommand{\faApple}{\FA\symbol{"F179}}

\begin{document}

\verb|Windows:| \faWindows \par
\verb|Linux  :| \faLinux \par
\verb|Apple  :| \faApple

\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably have an outdated version of the font installed (the one that comes with TeX Live is outdated). Could you check if you have the font installed as a system font and what version it is? Also are you using TeX Live?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @dcmst How do I check if the font is installed as a system font?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is the same as the linked question, I added it.

Comment: I'm using TeX Live 2014 and OpenSuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using an outdated version of the Font Awesome font (maybe the one that comes with the CTAN package).

There two ways to fix this.

### Adding the updated version of FontAwesome to the texmf-tree

Download the fontawesome latest version from their site: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Extract the FontAwesome.otf file and put it into the TeX Live tree

```
<your-texlive-path>/texmf-local/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf
```

If there is no such directory, create it.

### Install the updated version of the font as a system font

This depends on your OS, in OpenSUSE you need to search in the package manager and it will install the font for you.

The system font should take precedence over the TeX Live font (I think...)

At this point you can compile your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontawesome}

\newcommand{\faWindows}{\FA\symbol{"F17A}}
\newcommand{\faLinux}{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}
\newcommand{\faApple}{\FA\symbol{"F179}}

\begin{document}

\verb|Windows:| \faWindows \par
\verb|Linux  :| \faLinux \par
\verb|Apple  :| \faApple

\end{document}
```

And it will work

Comment: dcmst ok, that was it, I used the first method. Thanks.