# Possibillity to add additional key to MenuKey

Tags: packages, menukeys

Is it possible to add my custom key to the `menukey` package for a document?

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}


\begin{document}
\keys{\myCustomKey + R}
\end{document}
```

I am asking, since I am working on a cheatsheet for myself about tmux. And I do not want to write out my prefix everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution [Create Windows symbol (and Apple logo) in package “Menukeys”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387952/create-windows-symbol-and-apple-logo-in-package-menukeys?rq=1)

The example in the answer uses fontawesome, but for only text keys you can use `\textsf{CapsLock}`

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\makeatletter
\tw@make@key@box{OS@mac}{\faApple}
\tw@make@key@box{OS@win}{\faWindows}
\tw@make@key@macro*{\OS}
\makeatother
```